# Drupal 8: How do I add JS files inside libraries conditionally based on versions of IE7 and IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, drupal, conditional-statements, yaml

In Drupal 8, how would you load a JS file inside a library to only load on IE8 but not lte IE7?

I have the following added which correctly loads only on IE8 and lower.

```
js:
    js/script.js: { browsers: { IE: 'lte IE 8', '!IE': false } }
```

But, how would I only load this on IE8? and also how would I load a different js file for IE7?
Would this work for example:

```
js:
    js/script.js: { browsers: { IE: 'IE 8', 'IE 7': false,  '!IE': false } }
```

Comment: IE has built in functionality for this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx

Comment: @backpackcoder Thanks, have any knowledge of this working for Drupal 8?

Comment: my answer works in drupal or anywhere else. in the future you need to post your requirements in the question. tagging drupal does not tell me your using drupal. do you know how many people tag java on their javascript questions?

Comment: I've updated my question. Yes your are correct, your answer works if you place it straight into the head of any page, however, Drupal being php based its best practice to load them inside a library.yml file. Was looking for someone with knowledge in Drupal 8 and loading JS files.

Comment: @NoDirection it does not belong in a yaml configuration file. it belongs in the template (twig) file.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. It could go in html.html.twig - however I'm looking for the correct way of adding JS in Drupal through the use of libraries in my custom module.

Comment: so we've established that you cannot do this yaml and twig isn't good enough for you. so what exactly do you want? the only thing left is a javascript-only solution and there are threads all over stack overflow on how to do that..

Comment: Like I said, I've after someone with some Drupal 8 knowledge as to how I would go about this in a custom module/theme. I can't use template files for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
<script src="ie8only.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Using IE conditionals..

The above will only load on IE >= 8

see: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for a way to do this within yml and drupal 8 though.

Comment: and i'm clairvoyant or what?

Comment: Sorry thought I added Drupal 8 in the question

Comment: Here's the docs for adding conditional css in Drupal 8.   https://www.drupal.org/node/2659496